# Map layer is not defined

Tags: dictionary, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to do a point cluster layer based on the JSON objects I obtained from database. Here is my JavaScript to plot a point cluster layer:

```
function addClusters() {
$.ajax({
    url: "index.aspx/getBusCommuter",
    type: "POST",
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data.d);
        $.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) {
            var coordXicon = jsondata.BusStopX;
            var coordYicon = jsondata.BusStopY;
            var commuterAmt = jsondata.CommuterAmt;

            var latlng = new esri.geometry.Point({ "x": coordXicon, "y": coordYicon, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 4326 } });

            // cluster layer that uses OpenLayers style clustering
            clusterLayer = new ClusterLayer({
                "data": commuterAmt,
                "distance": 100,
                "id": "clusters",
                "labelColor": "#fff",
                "labelOffset": 10,
                "resolution": map.extent.getWidth() / map.width,
                "singleColor": "#888"
            });
            var defaultSym = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setSize(4);
            var renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer(defaultSym, "clusterCount");

            var picBaseUrl = "http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/";
            var blue = new PictureMarkerSymbol(picBaseUrl + "BluePin1LargeB.png", 32, 32).setOffset(0, 15);
            var green = new PictureMarkerSymbol(picBaseUrl + "GreenPin1LargeB.png", 64, 64).setOffset(0, 15);
            var red = new PictureMarkerSymbol(picBaseUrl + "RedPin1LargeB.png", 72, 72).setOffset(0, 15);
            renderer.addBreak(0, 2, blue);
            renderer.addBreak(2, 200, green);
            renderer.addBreak(200, 1001, red);

            clusterLayer.setRenderer(renderer);
            map.addLayer(clusterLayer);
        });
    },
    error: function (request, state, errors) {
    }
});
}
```

However, when I try to run it, it told me an error message which is clusterLayer is not defined. I wonder which part I missed and am I doing in the correct way.

Also, I wonder is it possible/correct to set the commuterAmt I obtained to data so that for each point on the map will be attached with the correct amount?

I get the reference from: [ArcGIS Documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the sample code ArcGIS Documentation
Include ClusterLayer.js from extras direxctory

```
 var dojoConfig = { 
        paths: {
          extras: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/extras"
        }
      };
```

then in your code  use

```
define dojo.provide("extras.ClusterLayer");
```

and call

```
clusterLayer = new extras.ClusterLayer({
                "data": commuterAmt,
                "distance": 100,
                "id": "clusters",
                "labelColor": "#fff",
                "labelOffset": 10,
                "resolution": map.extent.getWidth() / map.width,
                "singleColor": "#888"
            });
```